# Code skipping lines in debugging

Tags: c#

I have run into this problem before, many years back, and remember that the usual causes to this type of scenario are due to 1.) Threading or 2.) the program silently failing somewhere due to some exception.

Before posting here I encased the faulty code in a try and catch to see if it was failing but to no avail did not reach the catch block once.

I also scanned the project using CTRL.FIND "Thread" to see if there was any threading the in the project but there was not. Two scenarios ruled out..

I am not completely sure what is causing the below piece of code to skip the if block.

*Purpose of the code: To find the nth Prime number and test it using various scenarios*

### Faulty Piece of Code  aka (Implementation.cs) class

```
 public int FindNthPrimeNumber(int n)
    {

        if (n > 0) //code evaluates condition here but completely skips whats inside the braces
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Heyyy I got hit!");
        }

        return n;
    }
```

Comment: It won't enter the `if` block if the condition isn't true. What's the value of `n` when you're in the debugger.

Comment: The values are always greater than n in the tests. The first value is 5 and the second one I believe is 27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Debug.WriteLine` call might not be hit because you run in Release mode, hence it is optimized away.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that it was running in release. Let me double check everything before marking your answer correct.